# Cannot read property of setState of undefined REACT

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, binding, this

I'm trying to set the state of my FileList component, but I keep getting an error

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
>   from line 43 - this.setState({list: entries});

I've bound the function to this, as suggested online, does anyone know how to get this to work

```
 export default class FileList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getList = this.getList.bind(this);
    this.renderFiles = this.renderFiles.bind(this);
    this.state = {
    zipFile: props.zipFile,
    uploadPressed: props.uploadPressed,
    list: []
    }
  }

  getList() {
    var entries = new Array;
      let zip = new JSZip(); 
      JSZip.loadAsync(this.state.zipFile).then(function (zip) {
        zip.forEach(function (zipEntry) {
          if(zipEntry.split('/')[1] === "color"){
            if(zipEntry.endsWith('.png')) {
              entries.push(zipEntry.split('/').pop());
            } else if (zipEntry.endsWith('/')) {
            } else {
            }
          } else if(zipEntry.split('/')[1] === "mono") {
            if(zipEntry.endsWith('.png')) {
              entries.push(zipEntry.split('/').pop());
            } else if (zipEntry.endsWith('/')) {
            } else {
            }
          } else if(zipEntry.endsWith('.sslt')) {
          } else {
          }
        });
        alert(entries[0]);
        this.setState({list: entries});
      });
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="file-list">
              <div className="list-zip" >
                <div className="list-zip-name">
                  {this.state.zipFile.name}
                </div>
                <div className="list-zip-size">
                  {this.state.zipFile.size} Bytes
                </div>
                <div className="list-zip-x" >
                  <button className="x-button" onClick={close}>X</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr className="hr"/>
            {this.renderFiles()}
          </div>
  }

  renderFiles() {
    if(this.state.uploadPressed === true) {
    this.getList();
    return <File fileName={this.state.list[0]} />
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your callback functions with arrow ones:

```
....
JSZip.loadAsync(this.state.zipFile).then( zip => {
zip.forEach( zipEntry => {
    if(zipEntry.split('/')[1] === "color"){
...
```

You have a `.bind` for your main function but inside this function you are using regular callback functions for `.then` and `forEach` methods. Those functions create their own scope and you are loosing `this`. With arrow functions you won't loose `this`' scope.

Bonus info: You can use an arrow function for your getList function also. With this way you won't need to bind it in your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

A part from the fact that you should be using arrow functions to avoid loosing the current context as already reported by other users you have another error that will raise as soon as you fix the previous.

you're calling `setState` inside the `render` method, this will create an infinite loop, to avoid it just put the `getList` method inside the `componentDidMount` hook

Comment: Nice catch, I missed that one. But instead of being an answer this would be a comment. Or you can widen your answer with the first problem, then OP would accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a scoping problem. Your callback function doesn't have access to the component's `this`.
You need to use `.bind(this)` or an arrow operator (`() => {}`) to access `this` within your function